# Custom layer updates

Tags: tensorflow, keras

i want to create a custom layer with weights that update only in training phase.

from the official documentation this is the way:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Layer

class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        return K.dot(x, self.kernel)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

in [this github repo](https://github.com/handongfeng/MNIST-center-loss/blob/72cf16bf351868f3400fa037b7332856ba5c565c/centerLoss_MNIST.py#L61) 
the author added

```
new_centers = self.centers - self.alpha * delta_centers
self.add_update((self.centers, new_centers), x)
```

where `self.centers` are the weights.

I cant understand why self.add_update is useful in that situation.
Weights are not updated if i dont add self.add_update? If not, why `new_centers` must be in the updates list and not in the inputs list?And why x is a requirement?

from the source code, 
`self.add_update(updates, inputs)`

updates: update op or list of update ops to add to the layer.

inputs: input tensor or list of inputs tensors to mark the updates as conditional on these inputs.If None is passed, the updates are assumed unconditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of weights:

- Trainable = Updated automatically by the optimizer with backpropagation
- Untrainable = Not updated by backpropagation

For the trainable weights, it's really not recommended to use updates, you will be mixing the optimizer's updates with your own updates and that could cause many issues

For the untrainable weights, you can do whatever you want. Sometimes you want constants and you will do nothing, sometimes, you want these weights to change (but not via backpropagation)

Notice how in that example the weights updated by the user are untrainable:

```
 self.centers = self.add_weight(name='centers',
                                   shape=(10, 2),
                                   initializer='uniform',
                                   
                                   #UNTRAINABLE 
                                   trainable=False)
```

But the user wants these weights to be updated following some rules. I don't know what they are doing there (didn't analyse the code), but I assume that they are calculating, for instance, something similar to the center point of a group of images, and each batch will have this center in a different position. They want to update this position.

A classical example is the `BatchNormalization` layer. Besides having trainable `scale` and `bias` weights used to rescale the outputs, they have the `mean` and `variance` weights. These are statistical properties of the data that need to be updated with every batch.

You are not training the "mean" or the "variance", but each batch of data updates these values.

---

### How does it work?

This is obscure and lies deep down in Keras code.

We need the update operation so we make sure `self.centers` will have new values for every batch, otherwise it won't.

We use `self.add_update` in a layer to register that this variable should be updated. (We do similar things in custom optimizers as well, the optimizers contain the updates to the weights made via backpropagation)

Later in the [source code for training the model](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py), Keras will collect all these registered updates and make a train function. Somewhere inside this, these updates will be applied to the vars:

```
#inside a training function from keras
with K.name_scope('training'):
            with K.name_scope(self.optimizer.__class__.__name__):
                training_updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(
                    params=self._collected_trainable_weights,
                    loss=self.total_loss)
            updates = (self.updates +   #probably the updates registered in layers    
                       training_updates + #the updates registered in optimizers    
                       self.metrics_updates) #don't know.... 
            # Gets loss and metrics. Updates weights at each call.
            self.train_function = K.function(
                inputs,
                [self.total_loss] + self.metrics_tensors,
                updates=updates,
                name='train_function',
                **self._function_kwargs)
```

Comment: in ```self.add_update((self.centers, new_centers), x)``` i assume that self.centers are replaced by new_centers..But i cant understand the mechanism of the self.add_update, they are both update ops? how one replaces another?

Comment: The need for the update ops is clear: you can't do `self.centers = ...`, because this would disassociate the var `self.centers` from the tensor it should be pointing to. (The tensors in Keras are static entities in a graph, independent from data. Their values only exist when you start training/predicting and "feed" the graph with values). Maybe these registers are something to tell Keras not to erase these vars between batches.

Comment: But how it works internally is something I don't understand entirely. Yes, this line you mentioned replaces the value of `self.centers` with the values of `new_centers`. You use `self.add_update` so you tell keras that you want to update the value of `self.centers` (otherwise you won't change its value). How keras does it internally? That's hard to say, we must analyse the source code deeply.

Comment: but the docs says that "update_ops" can be a list so if instead of (self.centers, new_centers) i had 3 variables (self.centers, new_centers, other_centers), do you know what could happen?

Comment: This list should be `[(var1, new_val1), (var2, new_val2), (var3, new_val3)]`; You can see this in line 678 here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L678